# react-query how to use useInfiniteQuery?

Tags: typescript, react-query

I'm tying to passing query to getAnalysisListByPatientIdApi so I tried to put query into first parameter of array of useInfiniteQuery like [useQuery](https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/guides/queries#array-keys)

```
  const { data: analyses } = useInfiniteQuery(
    ['getAnalysesByPatientIdApi', { patientId: selectedPatientId }],
    getAnalysisListByPatientIdApi,
    {
      getFetchMore: (lastGroup, allGroups) => {
        const morePagesExist = lastGroup?.data.result.contents.length === 9
        if (!morePagesExist) return false
        return allGroups.length + 1
      },
    },
  )
```

```
export const getAnalysisListByPatientIdApi = (_: string, query?: AnalysisListPatientQuery) => {
// should get query from useInfiniteQuery
  return api.post<PagingResponse<AnalysisListPatientResponse>>(`/analysis/list/patient`, {
    page: query?.page || 1,
    size: query?.size || 9,
    patientId: query?.patientId || '',
  })
}
```

I expected to get { patientId: selectedPatientId } from useInfiniteQuery in getAnalysisListByPatientIdApi, but an error occurs: `Type '{ patientId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

How to solve this? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yay~! I did it on my own. For whom want to know how to use useInfiniteQuery...

The key point is useInfiniteQuery is pass cursor to exampleApi by itself. All you have to do is implementing `getFetchMore`

```
import React from "react";
import { useInfiniteQuery } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query-devtools";
import axios from "./fakeApis/axios";

const exampleApi = async (_: any, cursor: number) => {
  console.log(_, cursor);
  return await await axios.post(`/list/${cursor || 1}`);
};

export function App() {
  const { canFetchMore, isLoading, error, data, fetchMore } = useInfiniteQuery(
    "repoData",
    exampleApi,
    {
      getFetchMore: (lastGroup, allGroups) => {
        let morePagesExist = true;
        if (lastGroup && lastGroup.data.result) {
          morePagesExist = lastGroup.data.result !== null;
          console.log(morePagesExist);
        }
        if (!morePagesExist) return false;
        console.log(lastGroup?.data);
        // returns next cursor which will send to the cursor of eaxmpleApi
        return lastGroup?.data?.result?.currentPageNo + 1 || false;
      }
    }
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <div>"Loading..."</div>}
      {error && <div>"An error has occurred: " + error.message</div>}
      <button
        disabled={!canFetchMore}
        onClick={(e) => {
          fetchMore();
        }}
      >
        fetch more
      </button>
      {data?.map((o, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {JSON.stringify(o?.data?.result?.contents, 0, 1)}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-useinfinitequery-be62c?file=/src/App.tsx